# NG5002: Cannot parse expression. @for loop expression must match the pattern "<identifier> of <expression>"

Tags: angular, angular17

after migrating to new angular 17 and updating my template, ng serve throws this message
NG5002: Cannot parse expression. @for loop expression must match the pattern " of
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some diging,
it was because of Capital "O" of "Of"

for some bugs i believe, below line:

```
@for (relation Of detail.Relations; track relation) {
```

should be changed to (after auto upgrading by angular tools)

```
@for (relation of detail.Relations; track relation) {
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add async pipe with this for Observables?? Suppose i have `@for (relation of detailObserver; track relation) { }.` In this case how i can use the async pipe with this?  NOTE:  this does not work `@for (relation of (detailObserver | async); track relation) { }`